# Does bokehs `image_rgba()` support hovertools?

Tags: python, tooltip, bokeh

So I want tooltips to show up for all glyphs below (hence I use "hover").  I reduced my custom tooltips to just show the default ones bokeh uses.

```
p = figure(width=width, height=height, 
                   x_range=x_range, y_range=y_range, 
                   tools="hover")

line_glyphs = p.segment(
             x0='hex_x', y0='hex_y', x1='mercator_x', y1='mercator_y', 
             source=source, 
             line_width=2, line_alpha=0.8,
             line_color='fill_color', line_dash='line_dash', 
             hover_line_color='gold', hover_line_dash='solid')
        
img_glyphs = p.image_rgba(
            image='hex_rgba',
            x='hex_x', y='hex_y',
            dw='hex_size', dw_units="screen",
            dh='hex_size', dh_units="screen",
            anchor="center_center",
            source=source)
        
circle_glyphs = p.circle(
            x='mercator_x', y='mercator_y', 
            size=8, fill_color='fill_color', line_color='gold', 
            source=source)
```

Tooltips show for all the lines and circles, but not the for any of the image_rgba glyphs.
All the data in source is correct (everything renders perfectly and I checked all the columns manually).

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Hello and Welcome on Stack Overflow. Please try to make your question more specific and make your code a [working minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Right now your `source` is unkown and it is not possible to reprocude your problem. In general the `image_rgba()` should work with a hovertool. See [this example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/examples/topics/images/image_rgba.html) and add `tools='hover'` to the `figure()`. If this in not what your are asking for, please update your post.